# Does tf::StampedTransform create a parent and child frame if they both do not exist?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
Quick question on tf::StampedTransform. By using that function in C++ does it create parent frame and child frame automatically?
EX:

```
 br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "banana", "basket"));
```

In this case does the frame `banana` and `basket` get created?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286774/does-tf::stampedtransform-create-a-parent-and-child-frame-if-they-both-do-not-exist?/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
That depends on how you define when a frame is "created".

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-03-27**:
I guess my question is where is a frame defined? Within the broadcasters CPP file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After publishing the transform between 'banana' and 'basket' you can lookup the transform between them on a TransformListener as soon as the message has been received.

There is no explicit creation of a frame, there are only transforms stored between frames. That's why @gvdhoorn is referencing. It will automatically traverse any existing transforms to attempt to find any frame for which there is information.

The availability of a transform that references a frame will avoid the `LookupException` and cause a `ConnectivityException` or an `ExtrapolationException` so in that kind of reference the frame is "created" when published. It does not matter if it's a child or parent.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-03-27**:
so what is the origin of banana(parent frame)?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-03-28**:
There is none (or it is zero, depending on how you view it). You can look up the transform from `banana` to `basket`, but as long as neither `banana` nor `basket` have transforms available to any other frames, they are completely independent of anything else.